# How to Add a Shader to a Specific Part/Area of an Object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

So let's say I create a material in **Cycles** and let's say, I load an image texture onto a sword. It perfectly fits, all good.

Now, the sword I would load in would only be one part, it's just one big mesh.

So how would I select an area of the sword, let's say one part would be steel, and the other part would be (leather)? I just need to know how to add more than one shader on different parts of the object.

Comment: You can assign a material to specific veryices

Comment: You could do something like [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13697/2217), to control where the two shaders go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign another material to the faces that should have a different shader. Just go into edit mode, select the faces that should have a different material and assign it to the face:

[image]

Otherwise you could mix two shaders depending on a texture:

[image]

Comment: And I can assign the material to more than one object or only just that face?

Comment: A material is a collection of shaders/other nodes that tells Blender how to render a specific surface. They can have as many users as needed, it doesn't change the material at all. So yes, you can assign the material to any number of objects, faces, or a mixture of the two.

Comment: When I loaded the sword in, it like, had all these crazy vertices and faces and what not.

Comment: Wouldn't selecting materials for specific faces just become known as Texturing, or is that different?

Comment: @BinaryGreen Texturing is assigning a color or value to a model depending on texture coordinates, which do not necessarily depend on the faces of your mesh. Textures are usually defined on a sub-face level and thus can help you change materials inside a face.